# Difference between "I write novels" and "I am a novelist"

Tags: sentence-meaning

When someone asks me "What do you do?"...

Do you think my following two answers have similar meaning and give him/her the same impression?

A: I write novels.

B: I am a novelist.

Comment: Why do you think they might be different?

Comment: I think a novelist implies it's a profession, i.e. a subset of those who write novels, but I can not find anything to back that up. I'd be interested to know if there is a difference. +1

Comment: @Bee I think you might be on to something, but it would help us if the author could [edit] their question to explain their thinking so we can make sure our answers cover that part.

Comment: Notice that according to the Cambridge Dictionary, novelist = a person who writes novels. The words "professional" or "for a living" are not present in the definition. I think that the difference between your sentences is subjective and your question is primarily opinion-based. You should ask him/her about his/her impression.

Comment: @Bee it would be nice if there was a clearly defined difference like there is between *I'm a planner* and *I make plans*, and I almost perceive one, but also can't find any evidence

Comment: @Smock, as Rubio said, I think it's mostly just the way it's interpreted but maybe it can just be inferred from your example (and, I'm sure, countless others).

Answer (score 1):

It's a question of focus.

- **I write novels** *Describes something I do*
- **I am a novelist** *Describes something I am*

When you say what you are, you are describing things which you consider to define you, and one of the most common is to describe your profession.   Obviously the implication is that a writer writes, a novelist writes novels etc.

We can make distinctions when the obvious case doesn't apply:

- **I'm a novelist, but I haven't written a novel in years**

Sometimes there are qualifications:

- **I still consider myself a novelest, but I haven't written a novel in years**
- **I'm really a scriptwriter, but I write novels too**
- **I'm a pilot, but I haven't flown for years**
- **He's a pilot, but I don't know if he still flies**
- **He's a pilot -- well, a retired pilot at least**
- **Well, yes I drive, but I wouldn't call myself a driver**

Many will only use "novelist" for an acknowledged writer of novels.

- **I write novels, but I wouldn't call myself a novelist until I've had a few published**

Many will use "novelist" and similar for the inner nature:

- **He's a novelist at heart, but writes for a newspaper**